# “Sad face,” “sad time,” and “sad friend”

Tags: adjectives

A sad face means a face by which sadness is shown.

A sad time means a time when sadness is shown.

Then, technically, can a sad friend means a friend by whom sadness is shown?

It’s a little bit ambiguous though.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that ```a sad time``` identifies a time when sadness is *experienced*.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney ❤

Comment: Congratulations, you have discovered the concept of [metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sad" has two primary uses as an adjective. When describing a person, it usually refers to their feelings, or mood. When describing most other things, it usually means that the thing either causes sadness, or that it is overshadowed with a mood of sadness.

So, a 'sad time' would be a period marked with sadness. For example, the period following a bereavement might be called "a sad time", because people living through it are sad.

Because your friend is a person, "a sad friend" would mean a person who **is** sad, perhaps going through a period of sadness. I can't see how anyone would interpret that any other way. I'm not even sure what you mean by "a friend by whom sadness is shown".

Note that in British English, "sad" is also used colloquially to mean *pathetic*.

Comment: It’s projection (the unconscious transfer of one's own desires or emotions to another person) of feeling.

Comment: @user0203 If you mean your friend listens to and reflects your own sadness, it sounds like you have an *empathetic* friend.

Comment: Yes! What an empathetic and sad friend!

Comment: @user0203 An empathetic person might say they "were feeling sad for you", but it seems odd for you to describe them as sad when it is actually you that is sad. Similarly, "grieving" when describing a person tends to exclusively mean the bereaved. Friends might 'grieve' with you, but "the grieving" usually means the closest family.

Comment: 'Note that in British English, "sad" is also used colloquially to mean pathetic.' — Trump was a good advocate of this usage across the pond too :)